# ExtJs 4 GridPanel with CellEditing: data entered is lost on failed validation

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs4, editing, gridpanel

I am using a ExtJs Grid with the CellEditing plugin. It works perfectly except that invalid values are lost when it fails the validation I imposed on it.

For example, if I have a editable textfield in the grid that doesn't allow values over 10 characters, and the user enters "*olympicssucks*" the validation will fail and a red box will appear around the textfield. When the user clicks out of the field the value "*olympicssucks*" will be lost.

I want the grid to *still save* the invalid data, and keep the red box around it.

Another (maybe more clear) example:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/cell-editing.html
Try editing the first cellvalue: "*Adder's-Tongue*" and make it empty. Notice the red box and validation message. Now click out of the box. The failed validation will ***revert the cell back to its original value***, *Adder's-Tongue*.

---

***tl;dr:*** My question, restated, is that ***I want to keep the invalid value, and yet still have validation displaying a red box around it***. I'm sure its possible, but how is it done?

What I've tried:

1. I've looked into **Ext.Editor** and it seems promising because it has a config property called **revertInvalid** that does *exactly* what I want. Unfortunately, it seems that the **CellEditing** plugin does not seem to use **Ext.Editor**. I've tried providing a **Ext.Editor** into the **Editor** field of the grid column, but that produced un-editable text.
2. I've tried placing **revertInvalid** everywhere I could but this was always a far-shot.

---

Code:

```
    var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1
    });

    var grid = {
            xtype: 'grid', store: dataStore, plugins: [cellEditing],
            columns: [
                {
                    text: 'Items', dataIndex: 'items', flex: 1, sortable : false,
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        validator: function(value) { //custom validator to return false when value is empty and other conditions}
                },
                //...
           ],
           tbar: [{
                xtype: 'button', text: 'Add ' + type,  
                handler: function() {
                    dataStore.insert(0, {items: 'New ' + type});
                    cellEditing.startEditByPosition({row: 0, column: 0});                           
                }
           }]
    }
```

Comment: When you are done editing a cell, it saves the value to the store. And the grid is a representation of the store. You can prolly play around with the css of the cell itself ( eg mark it as red on an onsave ), but you cannot use a traditional "validator" function. ( that I know of atleast )

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm afraid that I have to go through annoying workarounds. It's just that after seeing **revertInvalid** being EXACTLY what I wanted, I was hoping that there was something similar for GridPanel and CellEditing.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (Extjs 4.2):

```
Ext.override(Ext.Editor, { revertInvalid: false });
```

Comment: could you post a short snippet on jsfiddle? I'd like to verify this and I don't have access to the old codebase I was working on.

Comment: sorry, the code comes from a very complex and highly dynamic UI generation solution that powers an ERP. is really hard to extract a snippet

Answer (score 0):

It very may well be that Sencha has not yet fully developed the ***revertInvalid*** field, and that its simple functionality does not yet work. To those looking for a workaround, you may have to mess with the CSS of the grid cell itself to custom-mark it as invalid.

Comment: I don't think so, the documentation states: "Available since: 1.1.0".

Answer (score 0):

see http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?271318-Ext.Editor-revertInvalid-false-what-is-the-expected-behavior&p=994118#post994118

to me it is a bug in ExtJs that you can fix by overriding the completeEdit function of Ext.editor